# Keyboard show disables modal where the TextInput is

Tags: reactjs, react-native, keyboard

I have Modal that appears when pressing on edit button on specific section. Sections are comments displayed with FlatList. Interesting thing is when I open edit panel and click on TextInput to edit text from that comment keyboard shows up and here is what happens:
If the edit button of that comment is above the keyboard height (that will shows later when I press the TextInput in edit Modal) everything works perfectly. But when I press the edit button and its located bellow keyboard height (basically if the position of button is ,,inside,, of keyboard position) when I press the TextInput in edit Modal, Modal get closed without any logic. And since I render modal as Pure.Component for each section and it is visible by bool value in each comment state, when I press edit button state changes to true, but when this problem happens state is not updated, it's still true and I can not activate edit Modal again, since it looks like its already open. And I can open Modal of any other comment without problem. What can cause the problem or what am I doing wrong?

If you need any more details let me know. I do not know what part of code should I post here since I do not know what cause the problem, but it is about Keyboard height for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Keyboard is messing things up. I made a workaround by making scrollToIndex, so when ever I press on edit button it will move that comment to be first displayed, that way it will always be above Keyboard.